# How to deal with long task Layout?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, layout, web-performance

I have high blocking time on my page and I'd like to reduce it.

My problem is: how to deal with long task on layout ?

I know there is also issue long task on JS but regarding to this [Optimize Long Tasks](https://web.dev/optimize-long-tasks) I will fix this problem, but I can't find proper information about how to deal with layout long task

[image]

Comment: Maybe start with MDN? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance

Comment: @Adam this may help i will check it

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested by this presentation, that explains why layout or painting can be long and how to fix them: https://nolanlawson.github.io/css-talk-2022/#1